# How can I find duplicate values among prefixed and non prefixed values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have these values in my database for this ID string that look like the following:

```
My_ID_String
=============
ABC123
123
ABC456
798
```

My end goal is to replace anything containing ABC with no prefix. But the challenge I ran across is that this column have must be unique values. I have a plan to address that. However, what I'm trying to accomplish is identify the ones that have a duplicate if I remove the prefix out of place. In other words, I want a query to return the results of ABC456, but not ABC123 since that would result in a duplicate if I done a replace function.

Expected Results:

```
My_ID_String
============
ABC456
```

Answer (score 1):

Just another option

**Example**

```
;with cte as (
Select Top 1 with ties *
 From  YourTable
 Order By sum(1) over (partition by replace(My_ID_String,'ABC','') )
)
Select * 
 From  cte 
 Where My_ID_String like 'ABC%'
```

**Returns**

```
My_ID_String
ABC456
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
SELECT My_Id_String  AS MyIdString
FROM tab
WHERE My_Id_String LIKE 'ABC%'
EXCEPT
SELECT 'ABC' + My_Id_String
FROM tab
WHERE My_Id_String NOT LIKE 'ABC%'
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9e006549f6f50fbd31b92938022aa761)**

Answer (score 0):

Is that what are you trying to do

```
WITH StrTable AS
(
SELECT 'ABC123' My_ID_String
UNION 
SELECT '12355555'
UNION
SELECT 'ABC456'
UNION
SELECT NULL
UNION
SELECT 'DEF123'
UNION
SELECT 'DEF456'
UNION
SELECT 'GHI123'
UNION
SELECT 'GHI456'
UNION
SELECT 'GHI789'
)
SELECT CONCAT( LEFT(My_ID_String, 3),
               MAX(REPLACE(My_ID_String, LEFT(My_ID_String, 3), ''))
             ) Result
FROM StrTable
WHERE TRY_CAST(LEFT(My_ID_String, 3) AS INT) IS NULL
      AND My_ID_String IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY LEFT(My_ID_String, 3);
```

**Returns:**

```
+--------+
| Result |
+--------+
| ABC456 |
| DEF456 |
| GHI789 |
+--------+
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=41f021117702d3ddb8479495c8d2dfb9)**

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems the end goal here it to get all the distinct values you could do both pieces of this in a single step. Just get the distinct values you want while eliminating the duplicates. Something like this might be what you are looking for.

```
declare @Something table
(
    My_ID_String varchar(50)
)
insert @Something values
('ABC123')
, ('123')
, ('ABC456')
, ('798')

select case when count(replace(s.My_ID_String, 'ABC', '')) = 1 then max(s.My_ID_String) else max(replace(s.My_ID_String, 'ABC', '')) end
from @Something s
group by replace(s.My_ID_String, 'ABC', '')
```